# UIButtons as Tab Bar?

Tags: iphone, uinavigationcontroller, uibutton, uitabbar

I am trying to do something similar to this app (Bottom Tab).
http://itunes.apple.com/gb/app/westfield-london/id409824812?mt=8

Basically it has 5 `UIButtons` and some of them work like a `UITabBar`. 
For some views the `UIButtons` (Tab) will stay at the bottom and for others it will not.
Once you click the Home button (top right) it goes to a View with an (Paging Images), NavigationBar at the top and `UIButtons` (Tab) at the bottom.

I want to know how it is possible to create such an App.
If you need any more details about the app, I will be happy to give.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That app is probably using a `UINavigationController` to manage navigation with the buttons all around the view. Once you tab on one of those, the app is actually using a `UITabBarController`, reusing the same images for the View, giving the illusion that the same buttons moved at the bottom.

Of course it's possible. They've done it! :)

Comment: Yeah, I thought of something similar (something along the lines of the Wordpress app too). However a few things are putting me off that thought. One of them is that the last tab (menu), once you click on any button within the Menu, the UIButtons tab still stays at the bottom. How is the possible?

Comment: If you go to the link of the application (I posted) and see screen two, it shows the Menu. Once you click any of the buttons within the menu, the UIButtons still appear at the bottom. For the first five Tabs I can understand why the Tab Bar will appear but for the others I don't, that is the problem. I hope you can understand.

Comment: As I said, the buttons in the menu are not related with the buttons in the tab bar. I mean, whatever button you tap on, the tab bar remains the same with the same five buttons. If you're wondering why the authors decided to keep the same 5 buttons in the tab bar...well, that's just a choice :) If you'd like you can decide that the buttons in the tab bar should depend on the button you pressed (a little bit more complex maybe, but possible).

Comment: I want to know how it is possible. I can understand if the Home has a navigation controller the controls the buttons and displays a UITabBarController. What about the Menu, how does it display the Tab bar or buttons as Tab. Does it again create a UINavigationController. I hope you understand.

Comment: Do you mean how they create the SpringBoard's like menu? They use a `UIPageControl`. It works in pair with a delegate and lets navigate among a number of views. Don't know if that's what you're looking for.